# <pre> tag formatting doesn't always apply properly

Tags: support, source-code, pre

I've just edited [Backup solutions for Rackspace cloud sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/95353/backup-solutions-for-rackspace-cloud-sites/95368#95368) to add `<pre>` tags around the shell script, and whilst the live preview showed the correct layout, when I save the edit I got a horrendous wrapped, non-`<pre>` version.  Looking at the HTML source, there's no `<pre>` tag (or equivalent) in there at all.  Markdown fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just indent by 4 spaces. Or use the toolbar button that does it for you.

The only reason to use `<pre>` is if you have some reason to avoid the automatic syntax highlighting.

And note that if you do use `<pre>` you must escape < and > to &lt; and &gt; within the pre block. That was your specific problem, but the easiest answer is .. indent 4 spaces.

Comment: What if you wanted to put links inside your fixed-width space-and-newline-preserving block?

Answer (score 0):

I just viewed source and saw the `pre` tag, both start and close. Perhaps Markdown got confused because you have what looks (to it) like Markdown inside the `pre`?

Try indent by 4 spaces perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

The post is truncated. Add whitespace (space/new line) at the end of the post (behind the `<pre>`). That could help.